# How do I extract a dynamic value from a varchar string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a `varchar` string as below

```
@msg='YOUR TRXN 30206008 CREDITED.FOR ANY QUERIES CONTACT US ON OUR HOTLINE'
```

I would like to extract the TRXN number from above string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the number always follows `'TRXN'`, you can use a combination of `substring`, `charindex`, `right`, `len` and `patindex` to extract the number:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(
            @msg, 
            CHARINDEX('TRXN', @msg) + 5, 
            PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', 
                     RIGHT(
                        @msg, LEN(@msg) - CHARINDEX('TRXN', @msg) - 4)
                    )
        )
```

Another, less cumbersome way is to use a stuff, but then you need 2 select statements:

```
SELECT @msg = STUFF(@msg, 1, CHARINDEX('TRXN', @msg) + 4, '') 

SELECT STUFF(@msg, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @msg), LEN(@msg), '')
```

If your transaction number is always followed by `'CREDITED'` you can use a simpler select statement:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(
            @msg, 
            CHARINDEX('TRXN', @msg) + 5, 
            CHARINDEX('CREDITED', @msg) - CHARINDEX('TRXN', @msg) - 5
        )
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/MWSD31339)